# Substr in angularJS to fetch the initials of the full name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My question is related to creating substr in Angular.JS

Suppose i have a model:

```
$scope.myName = 'John Smith'
```

but when during the rendering of the model on the page i need only the initials of the name like:

```
<p>{{myName | some directive/filter }}<p>
```

Output should be :: JS

i tried creating many directives but unable to fetch the exact output even i have tried the limitTo filter but it give only the starting first 2 letters of the name.

[Workbook is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HM5MM3ps6wclRqeqKpQx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular
    .module('myApp',[])
    .run(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
    })
    .controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){


        $scope.myName = 'saurabh raman';
    }]).filter('filter', function() {

return function(input) {

    var name = input;
    var inls = name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
    inls = ((inls.shift() || '') + (inls.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
    return inls;
  }
});
```

view

```
<p>{{myName | filter}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With assumption that name tokens are separated by **SPACE** , as given in your question

```
 <body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
   <label>Name : {{name}}</label><br/>
   <label>Short Name : {{name|shortName}}</label>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.filter('shortName', function() {
          return function(x) {
        var shortName="", nameTokens=[];
        nameTokens = x.split(" ");
       nameTokens.forEach(function(token){ shortName+=token[0] });
       return shortName;
      };
    });
    app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'John Smith';
    }); 
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping there was a built-in filter for it, but it seems there isn't one, so I've created this filter:

```
var relConclusaoApp = angular.module("relatorioConclusaoApp", []);
relConclusaoApp.filter('onlyinitials', [function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (input) {
            return input
                .split(/\s+/)
                .filter(s => s.length > 2)
                .map(s => s.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase())
                .join(".")
                .concat(".")
        }
        return input;
    }
}])
```

This filter is going to transform *Floor Jansen* into *F.J.* (e.g.)
It should be used in your template as:

```
{{nameToBeTransformed | onlyinitials}}
```